# Proving that $b^6-2a^3b^3-2b^3+a^6-2a^3+1$ is never a nontrivial integer square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I'm trying to prove that if $a,b$ are integers, and $b^6-2a^3b^3-2b^3+a^6-2a^3+1$ is a square [integer], then $ab=0$.

What general tools are available to attack such a problem?

Comment: what makes you believe it is true?

Comment: General tools: congruences, size considerations (there are after a while large gaps between consecutive squares).

Comment: @dREaM: It arose "embedded" in the algebraic solution of another equation for which there are no solutions. As well, I have numerically verified it for many small numbers (currently checking $-1000 \le a,b \le 1000$).

Comment: So it looks like $(a^3+b^3-1)^2-4a^3b^3$, and switching the inner terms' signs causes the term $4a^3b^3$ to be interchanged into either $4a^3$ or $4b^3$...

Comment: For $a,b\gt 0$ size considerations should do the job. I cannot handle negatives.

Comment: Maybe look at it as a quadratic in one variable and consider the discriminant?